# EF Core 2 1-1 relationship unexpected behaviour

Tags: entity-framework-migrations, one-to-one, ef-core-2.0

I have a typical Parent : Child relationship. The classes are as follows:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child Child { get; set; }

}
```

and

```
public class Child
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

The model is quite simple too:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(p => p.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
    }
```

The migration looks like this:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Parent",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Parent", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Child",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ParentId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Child_Parent_ParentId",
                    column: x => x.ParentId,
                    principalTable: "Parent",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Child_ParentId",
            table: "Child",
            column: "ParentId",
            unique: true);
    }
```

which is pretty much what was expected. The FK is declared in the "Child" table.

If I add a new Child, however, things change quite unexpectedly. Here's the second child and the modified Parent:

```
public class Child2
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public /*virtual */Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Parent
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Child Child { get; set; }

    public Child2 Child2 { get; set; }
}
```

Again, nothing special about the model:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child>().HasOne(p => p.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>().Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>().HasOne(p => p.Parent).WithOne(p => p.Child2).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().HasKey(p => p.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>().Property(p => p.Name).HasMaxLength(256).IsRequired();
    }
```

And now the **surprise**. The new migration:

```
protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Child2",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child2", x => x.Id);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Parent",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Child2Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Parent", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Parent_Child2_Child2Id",
                    column: x => x.Child2Id,
                    principalTable: "Child2",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
            name: "Child",
            columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
                Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
                ParentId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
            },
            constraints: table =>
            {
                table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child", x => x.Id);
                table.ForeignKey(
                    name: "FK_Child_Parent_ParentId",
                    column: x => x.ParentId,
                    principalTable: "Parent",
                    principalColumn: "Id",
                    onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
            });

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Child_ParentId",
            table: "Child",
            column: "ParentId",
            unique: true);

        migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
            name: "IX_Parent_Child2Id",
            table: "Parent",
            column: "Child2Id",
            unique: true);
    }
```

One can easily spot the

> Child2Id

FK in Parent table while there's no such key for the Child table. Also, there's another surprise - the missing

> ParentId

FK in the Child2 table.

Things appear to be quite asymmetric and look much more like a chain of 1:1 relations than a parent with two children.
If, however, I add another child (code not pasted to avoid bloating) the "chain" is broken - the third child looks like the second, etc.

My questions are:

1. Why such **asymmetry** provided code is pretty much "copy-paste"?
2. Whatever I do (change `Child2` code location in `OnModelCreating()` and/or swap `Child` and `Child2` property order in `Parent`), `Child2` is generated the same way, that is FK in `Parent`. So, what makes EF choose `Child2` over `Child` for such generation? If there are three or more children `Child` is only generated as expected, all the rest are like `Child2`. What makes `Child` so "special" if I may "reverse" my surprise?

Any ideas?
Thanks.

**PS: No explicit FKs are allowed in code!**

**EDIT:** Commented out `virtual` in `Child2` to avoid asymmetry. In fact it is unrelated to the problem.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with declaring the Parent as "virtual" in Child2 and not in Child?

Comment: @NDUF: No, I'll remove it in the pasted code, so as not to mislead other people too. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

The answer is basically contained in the following **Note** inside the **Other Relationship Patterns - One-to-one** section of the [**Relationships**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation:

> EF will choose one of the entities to be the dependent based on its ability to detect a foreign key property. If the wrong entity is chosen as the dependent, you can use the Fluent API to correct this.

EF has no problem with one-to-many relationships because the many side is always the dependent. Also it has no problem with one-to-one relationships having explicit FK because the side with FK is the dependent.

But for one-to-one relationships without explicit FK like in your case, it's unclear which side the dependent, hence the choice is sort of random (it should probably being an exception) and thus unreliable.

As a rule of thumb, always explicitly specify the FK (thus the dependent entity) with `HasForeignKey` fluent API using the corresponding overload for explicit/shadow property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Child>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
    .WithOne(p => p.Child)
    .HasForeignKey<Child>("ParentId")
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

modelBuilder.Entity<Child2>()
    .HasOne(p => p.Parent)
    .WithOne(p => p.Child2)
    .HasForeignKey<Child2>("ParentId")
    .IsRequired()
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The generated migration is:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Parent",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Parent", x => x.Id);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Child",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        ParentId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Child_Parent_ParentId",
            column: x => x.ParentId,
            principalTable: "Parent",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });

migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "Child2",
    columns: table => new
    {
        Id = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false),
        Name = table.Column<string>(type: "nvarchar(256)", maxLength: 256, nullable: true),
        ParentId = table.Column<Guid>(type: "uniqueidentifier", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_Child2", x => x.Id);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_Child2_Parent_ParentId",
            column: x => x.ParentId,
            principalTable: "Parent",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

Comment: Even with shadow FKs EF chooses something unusual - it creates FKs on both sides. Specifying explicit FKs, as I said, is unacceptable. So, this does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: That's strange because in my test (and I always test before posting), using the above fluent relationship configuration produces the correct FKs. I'm using EFC 2.0 with SqlSever.

Comment: Do you have ParentId as a "real" property? In this case I believe you're right, the restriction however is, not to use "real" FKs but "shadow" ones. With shadow FKs even specified afrer WithMany() on the child side produces two FK - on both sides. Perhaps "shadows" are still too shady...

Comment: Good! It worked even without "real" FKs. Maybe the magic was with the explicit specification of the class on  which to create the "shadowed" FK: HasForeignKey<THE CHILD CLASS HERE!!!>("ParentId"). Thanks!